# Получить значение поля по ид с другого веб-сайта

Tags: c#, asp.net

Я хочу получить данные с другого сайта по ID. У меня есть поле на моей странице, и я хочу записать значение, которое я возьму с другого сайта по ID. Возможно ли получить значение поля по идентификатору с другого сайта? 
Пример: 
на моей странице у меня есть поле Sum, я хочу написать метод, который каждую минуту будет ходить на сайт www.test.com и брать значения поля ID = SumVal и записывать в мою переменную

Comment: вы вольны отправлять любые запросы на любые доступные сайты, но это не гарантирует, что вы получите какие-то полезные ответы на свои запросы.

Comment: Есть ли у того сайта API? Если да, то нужно пользоваться им. А так, шлите запросы, парсьте респонз. Но если тот сайт динамический на js, то ... В-общем, нужно знать, что за сайт.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov взять например сайт https://www.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/ с помощью curl запросов я вроде бы смог получить <div> но никак не могу вытащить динамические значение валют,  они попросту отсутствует в респонсе.

Comment: Значит значения подтягиваются динамически с помощью JavaScript. Значит нужно этот скрипт выполнять. Сделать это можно либо с помощью компонента WebBrowser, либо взять Selenium WebDriver, либо CefSharp.

Comment: В тырнете полным полно сервисов, предоставляющих курсы обмена валют. Нафига парсить сайт? | Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях, их никто не видит. Отредактируйте вопрос. Или задайте новый вопрос, создав новую тему.

Answer (score 0):

- U can use ajax request to your backend API.On BE side u can use HttpClient to get HTML markup of another site.
- When u have markup need find value by HtmlAgilityPack and XQuery.
- Return response to your ajax request.